# After trying to install ubuntu no OS is working

Tags: installation, boot, windows

I am very new to Ubuntu, i tried to install it from a usb stick but it got stuck on the swap partition so i tried quit and now i can not even boot on windows 8.

I tried also the boot repair and I get [this report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6015819/).

Any suggestions,i can not even enter into BIOS mode

Thank you in advance

Zampeta

Comment: ....ah dang. You've got a GPT system. This is going to be a toughie. In the end, the moral of the story is *never stop a running installation*.

Answer (score 0):

To get your Windows 8 BootLoader back you have to boot from a Windows Repair Disk, or your Windows installation disk, and run Startup Repair (fix programs that stop windows from booting).

Have a look at [this](http://www.tweakhound.com/2012/11/13/how-to-fix-the-windows-bootloader/) link.

Once your Windows is fixed, then if you want you can install Ubuntu by downloading the ISO, booting from it, and installing.For instructions check out this page http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Ubuntu LiveCD or bootable pen drive. Select 'Try Ubuntu', you can manually recover your grub and fix your MBR.

Open the terminal Ctrl+Alt+T and run fdisk -l to check the partition from which you want to recover GRUB 2.
From your attached link of report it is clear that your Ubuntu is installed in /dev/sda7 and Swap is in /dev/sda8. Thus you have to recover it from /dev/sda7.
Then run the following commands:

$sudo mkdir /media/sda7

$sudo mount /dev/sda7 /media/sda7

$sudo mount --bind /dev /media/sda7/dev

$sudo mount --bind /proc /media/sda7/proc

Now chroot into that partition by running the command given below:

$sudo chroot /media/sda7

Then re-install GRUB, as follows:

## grub-install /dev/sda

The output should be like what’s shown below:

Installation finished. No error reported.

If you get an error, then try the following command:

## grub-install --recheck /dev/sda

After a successful installation, exit from chroot and unmount the file systems that were mounted to recover GRUB. Now reboot:

## exit

$sudo umount /media/sda7/proc

$sudo umount /media/sda7/dev

$sudo umount /media/sda7

$sudo reboot

Just try it once.. If it fails then try to install Ubuntu again, if possible try to repeat this step after installing Ubuntu (if it says you don't have permission then try always execute the above commands using sudo )..

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i accidentally deleted everything and return the pc back to the shop.